# Fortran: Separate type-bound procedure from type definition in separate files

Tags: oop, fortran

I try to separate type bound procedure from the type definition in separate files.
But I failed. Here are the codes.

The main program is as follows,

```
program main
  !
  use def_mod
  use funcs_mod
  !
  implicit none
  !
  type(time_info_t) :: tinfo
  !
  continue
  !
  call tinfo%InitTimeInfo()
  !
  write(*,*) tinfo%it, tinfo%time
  !
end program main
```

The `def_mod` is as follows,

```
module def_mod
  !
  implicit none
  !
  public
  !
  type :: time_info_t
    !
    integer :: it
    real :: time
    !
    contains
    !
    procedure :: InitTimeInfo
    !
  end type time_info_t
  !
  type(time_info_t) :: time_info
  !
  interface
    !
    subroutine InitTimeInfo(this)
      !
      import time_info_t
      class(time_info_t) :: this
      !
    end subroutine InitTimeInfo
    !
  end interface
  !
contains
  !
  !
end module def_mod
```

The `funcs_mod` is as follows,

```
module funcs_mod
  !
  implicit none
  !
  public
  !
contains
  !
  subroutine InitTimeInfo(this)
    !
    use def_mod, only: time_info_t
    !
    class(time_info_t) :: this
    !
    continue
    !
    this%it = 0
    this%time = 4.0
    !
  end subroutine InitTimeInfo
  !
end module funcs_mod
```

I execute the following commands to compile and link the program.

```
ifort -c def.f90
ifort -c funcs.f90
ifort -o test test.f90 def.o funcs.o
```

It reports the following error.

```
/tmp/ifortigFJkD.o: In function `MAIN__':
test.f90:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `inittimeinfo_'
/tmp/ifortigFJkD.o:(.rodata+0x0): undefined reference to `inittimeinfo_'
```

I feel like that Fortran supports this feature. However, I do not understand why the above error is raised.

I've checked [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262948/oop-fortran-type-and-procedures-in-different-files). However, I do not think that post gives me the answer.

---

UPDATE[2020-08-25]: I do not think the sub-module feature of Fortran could accomplish my goal. My goal is explained as follows.

I'm developing a CFD solver based on a finite element method, trying to organize the solver in an organized way.

A finite element CFD solver could be organized to include several modules.

- grid
- space solver
- time solver
- infrastructures including data types, finite element operators
- other utility modules, for example, saving and writing solution file for restarting the simulation

Using CMake to compile and link them. And these modules are put in different folders under the root folder.

One important issue here is that some modules are in the lower level while some modules are in the higher level. The high level modules depend on the low level modules. Thus the derived type defined in the low level module cannot use the derived type defined in the high level module. This issue motivates me to separate the type-bound procedure from the type definition in separate files.

The `time_info_t` is defined in a low level `time_base` module located in the directory `base`. But the initialization procedure `Init` of `time_info_t` requires the information of the restart solution `rst_info` which is declared in the higher level `restart` module which is located in the directory `space`. This could result in a cross-dependency problem.

`time_info_t` is a common data structures used by many modules. So I would like to keep the definition of `time_info_t` in the low level module, but move the implementation of `time_info_t%Init` to a higher level module which is in another file.

So the sub-module feature of Fortran cannot solve this problem.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Hi, I know the sub-module feature. But I think that cannot solve my problem. I added more information about my question. Could you check it one more time? Thanks!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sorry for the confusion. I feel like that calling the Init procedure directly would be a good way. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface block declares an external procedure (a procedure that is not intrinsic and is not defined in a module). The subroutine subprogram in the module funcs_mod defines a module procedure. Those two types of procedure are not the same thing.

You don't provide a definition of an external procedure to the Fortran processor, so it complains.

Either move the procedure definition out of the module (make it a subroutine program unit), or use a separate module procedure and define the procedure in a submodule.

Comment: Hi, I know the sub-module feature. But I think that cannot solve my problem. I added more information about my question. Could you check it one more time? Thanks!

Comment: Two possible solutions to your problem are in the last sentence of me answer (and in the question/answer you linked to in your question). Why do you need the InitTimeInfo procedure to be in a module? Is it ever going to be called directly (as opposed to being called via the binding)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I feel like that calling the procedure directly would be a good method.